# Convert System::String^ into unsigned char*

Tags: string, c++-cli, unsigned-char

I have a C++-Dll which I am calling from a C# project. In a function I need a string as a parameter and then convert it to an unsigned char*. I am using System.String^ to convert the C#-String to a C++-String. How can I convert the String^ to an unsigned char * in C++?

I tried this but it isn't working:

```
void Function(String^ userInput)
{
    unsigned char* msg;
    strcpy((char*)msg, userInput); // Doesn't work    
}
```

Comment: I am calling an other function later in the code which needs an unsigned char*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with this code:

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
const unsigned char* str = (const unsigned char*) (Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(managedString)).ToPointer();
```

Also remeber to free the newly allocated resource with Marshal::FreeHGlobal(), when the string is no longer in use, otherwise you will have memory leak.

Comment: Thank you. I need an unsigned char* so I just changed the const to unsignded and now it is working.